# Launching an EXE file already stored on your computer via website

Tags: javascript, html, exe, launch

Is it possible to make a launcher for a website that opens a file installed on your computer published by the website, like a button?

For example, the user can install "blahblah.exe" onto their computer by downloading the installer from the website, and there could be a "Click here to launch blahblah.exe" button on your website, and when you click it, it opens blahblah.exe which was installed previously.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Can you imagine the potential security and privacy issues this would have if it was possible?

Thankfully, it is not possible, not by default.

With browser plugins this is possible, but you need to install these.

Comment: As demonstrated by every exploit that launches calc.exe ;-)

Comment: @Joey - That `calc.exe`... never trust it!

Comment: Well, there's a game called Roblox they have games that when you click Play, it opens software they already installed on your computer. So it must be possible?

Comment: Did you install something on your computer from the people that created the game?

Comment: Yes, I did. Perhaps I didn't write the question properly, I meant "to open a file the site installed on their computer."

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible, but not without either

1. an exploit for a vulnerability in the user's browser (or other component)
2. a plugin for a browser that specifically allows that kind of things.

So, in general no.

Special cases are for example:

- iTunes which registers an URI handler (so iTunes can launch when you click a special link)
- Some other software that includes a launcher as a browser plugin (Skype, iirc)

In both cases something has to be done by the user before it's possible (and that's how it should be, ideally).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, this is not possible.

Longer answer: You could do something with a browser extension, but of course you have to

- Write one
- Get the user to install it

This isn't allowed due to massive security risks. There are plenty of things you can do to an operating system just by running commands, so any malicious page you visit could potentially wipe your entire disk, steal your data or anything else someone might want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is like giving a robber the key to your front door. Here you go, feel free to start up any random program.

No it is not possible with a standard security settings on the browser. There are ways to do it with ActiveX in IE, but that requires very relaxed settings.

Or you can install some sort of [plug-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Running_applications) that can listen for an event and do it.